# Real time update with Angular 2 and Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, mean-stack

In Angular 2 I have a navbar and I show how many unread messages the person has. When the person clicks the message, it marks it as read. My database is marked as read, but the navbar doesn't update until I refresh the page entirely.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the you have a `navbar` Component into a `HomePage` Component, then in you home-page.ts file there has to be a variable:

```js
let isMessageRead: boolean = false;
```

You should then bind the navbar in home-page.html with the `isMessageRead` variable that should look like this:

```html
<navbar [read]="isMessageRead"></navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a normal way no need to any real time. Just add a flag and set to boolean and make an HTTP cal. real-time data means you need to use a socket and establish a socket connection.